# Adding TextBoxes to list

Tags: c#, winforms, list, textbox

I am trying to add a group of textboxes to a list.  I keep getting an error cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.TextBox'.  Not sure why I am getting this error.  Do I need to add a cast?
Here is my code.  The textboxes I want to add are in getValues.  I haven't worked a lot with windows forms so this error is a mystery for me.

```
class DiagnosticsExcelFile: ConfigForm
{
    string fileName = "";
    private ConfigForm configForm;
    Excel.Application xlApp = null;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
    List<TextBox> list = new List<TextBox>();

    public DiagnosticsExcelFile(ConfigForm config)
    {
       fileName = "Z:\\UCA\\Diagnostics.xlsx";
       this.configForm = config;
       this.list.Add(this.configForm.HighOffSetX); // get error here

    }

    private void getValues()
    {
      this.configForm.HighOffSetX.Text = "5.0";  
      this.configForm.HighOffSetY.Text = "5.0";  
      this.configForm.HighOffSetZ.Text = "5.0";  

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your list like:

```
List<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox> list = new List<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox>();
```

Currently your `List` is referring to TextBox from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.TextBox`.

Both `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel=` and `System.Windows.Forms` has a class `TextBox`, since you haven't shown  your using directives, I assume you have

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

and you don't have a using directive for `System.Windows.Forms`, therefore your code is considering your `List` to contain TextBoxes from Office Interop. *(By the way, if you have both references, then you will get an error for ambiguous reference to `TextBox`)*

By explicitly defining `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`, your error will go away.

Answer (score 3):

```
using TextBox = System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
```

I usually find this approach the most efficient. 
It doesn't require many code changes and allows to keep lines short.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying a full namespace, but you probably have:

```
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

in your code file.
The compiler can't tell which TextBox you mean.  You can fully qualify each type name, or alias one of the `using`s.

```
using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then you would refer to the Excel Textbox as xl.TextBox.  Specifying just `TextBox` would give you the `System.Windows.Forms` one that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the TextBox type from System.Windows.Forms.TextBox (maybe with a using TextBox = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.TextBox).

Try declaring your list with:

```
List<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox> list = new List<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is correct. The problem occurs when adding new members to the list. Try the following:

```
list.Add(HighOffSetX);
```

You dont need the whole "this" stuff at this point.